# Angular iterate only display one output

Tags: angular

I try iterate array value.. When I try to console.log my array, it produce values that I want .. but when I display the data, only one of the value of data got display. Here is my function

```
getEarning() {
    for (let booking of this.bookings) {
      if (booking.status == 'paid') {
        this.earn = booking.price * 0.6;
        console.log(this.earn);
      }
    }
  }
```

here how I display the data
`<p><span class="label">Earning: </span>RM {{earn}}</p>`

here is my console log result
[image]

and here the result of my display data
[image]

Comment: Your `earn` is being overwritten for each iteration. Yes, your `console.log` is correct, but when render in HTML, the `earn` will display the latest value.

Comment: i try use ngfor to loop the earn in html the only result i get the earning part went missing

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are looping through this.bookings and setting a new value to this.earn and console logging it in that point in time. So you only display the latest value of this.earn in your html file. There are several ways to solve this. The simplest way would be to calculate the earnings directly in your html. Thus, you don't need getEarning() in your ts file.

```html
<div *ngFor="let booking of bookings">
  ...
  <div class="label">Earning: {{booking * 0.6 | number: '1.2-2'}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can i handle the decimals bcs i need to display the earning in 2 decimals

Comment: @Shariffuddin Husain, you can use a pipe called Decimal Pipe. {{booking * 0.6 | number: '1.2-2'}}